# Difference between ConditionalOnClass and ConditionalOnBean

Tags: spring, conditional-statements

I have read through the doc about these two annotations.

ConditionalOnClass
@Conditional that only matches when the specified classes are on the classpath.

ConditionalOnBean
@Conditional that only matches when beans meeting all the specified requirements are already contained in the BeanFactory(some says container).

Im having a hard time understanding this two conditionals. The only difference I can see is one checks the classpath and the other checks the container. So here is my understanding:

1.classpath is the place where runtime finds the classes and other resource. So conditionalOnClass means it checks if class file exist in classpath folder(not initialized yet).
2. Container is where classes are initialized as beans and manages their lifecycle. so ConditionalOnBean is to checks whether those beans are in container.

Do I understand them correctly?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking if you've read the java doc correctly or is there an unstated question that you're hoping to have answered aswell?

Comment: I'm asking whether I understand classpath and container correctly and base on that the difference between those two conditions. I will rephrase my question to make more sense.

Comment: Okay, so you would like to know the difference between the classpath and the application context container?

Comment: yes, and hence how the \@ConditionalOnClass and \@ConditionalOnBean  works with them.

Comment: Then I think you've understood the difference. I would say the classpath contains all classes available to the JVM while the container contains instances of some of those classes.